# Marionette LayoutView's UI hash returns strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I have a LayoutView that I use as a "content viewer" in my app that opens up as a modal when certain content is clicked on.

There is a region in this LayoutView called contentModal that loads fine on the first load and the UI hash loads fine on the first load of this content viewer.

But after I close the viewer and then try and open it again by clicking on some other content, the UI hash instead of returning jQuery-selected objects, just returns an array of strings of the selector names ('.content-modal', '.text-link', etc).

Has anyone else experienced this before and can help me out with why this is happening?

Comment: Can you add some code for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this many times before. And the only solution I found was to  give a call to this.bindUIElements function in onRender.
The possible reason to this behaviour can be that you might be using same object which backbone.marionette is disposing internally.